# Disable FPS Meter in Chrome DevTools

Tags: google-chrome, web, google-chrome-devtools, javascript-debugger

When you press F12 in Chrome, it opens up Developer Tools.

In the latest versions, this comes with an FPS Meter to the left of the debug window. I have the latest version as of this post (v43).

I would like to know how I can hide the FPS meter in order to save a little screen real estate. Older search results say it is under settings, but I can't find it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press  <kbd>esc</kbd> to open the DevTools drawer. Then under the "Rendering" tab, uncheck "Show FPS meter".

Comment: That works, I also had "Enable continuous page repainting" enabled, that box was the actual thing I wanted to hide. Thank you!